# How to assign a property in object to the value of some property in same object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In code below I'm creating a circle objects and giving it's keys some values. I'm setting the radius property of the circle object to it's diameter divided by 2. When we console.log it's value, it returns NAN. How to fix this problem?

```
let circle = {
    posX: 40,
    posY: 70,
    diameter: 30,
    radius: this.diameter/2
}
console.log(circle.radius)
```

Comment: [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) does not refer to `circle`. You could call `circle.radius = circle.diameter/2` after the initial assignment or add it as a function to the object.

Comment: May I ask why you are setting both the `radius` and the `diameter` attributes, when you can easily calculate one from the other if/when you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class:

```
class Circle {
   posX;
   posY;
   diameter;
   radius;
   
   constructor(posX, posY, diameter){
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.radius = diameter / 2;
   }
}
```

Then when you instanciate it like the following, the radius is automatically set to diameter/2

```
let circle = new Circle(40, 70, 30);
// circle.radius is 15
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a method inside the object in order to do it, because you are using the `this` keyword, and it needs a function to work:

```js
let circle = {
    posX: 40,
    posY: 70,
    diameter: 30,
    radius: function () {
      return this.diameter/2;
    }
}

console.log(circle.radius())
```